# IntelliJ Idea ctrl+shift+enter works strange in Dart and Flutter projects

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

The versions :

> IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2018.3.4
>
> plugin : Flutter v33.3.2
>
> plugin : Dart v183.5901

I usually use most of the shortcuts, one of the shortcut that I most use is `ctrl + shift + enter` but it is working strange in `Dart`&`Flutter`.

```
  Widget buildSwipper() // cursor is here and I'm pressing the shortcut 'ctrl+shift+enter'

  Widget buildSteps() {...}
```

this is what I got after the press the `ctrl + shift + enter`

```
 Widget buildSwipper()

  {
    
  } Widget buildSteps() {...}
```

How can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Might be worth it to [file an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=Subsystem:%20Dart).

Comment: [I created a issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37710)